# Does ricordarsi require the preposition di?

Tags: prepositions

I have read the following sentence in a language learning tool:

> Vi ricordate quegli anni?

Shouldn't it be "Ricordate quegli anni?" or "Vi ricordate di quegli anni?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb “ricordarsi” can be used as a transitive verb or also as intransitive with preposition "di" when it refers to a noun. When it refers to another verb “di” should be used. Examples:

- “Ricordati di mettere fuori lo sporco”.
- “Ricordati lo sporco”.

Comment: How can it be intransitive if it refers to a noun?

Comment: If I say “I am waiting for you” the verb “to wait” is intransitive and it needs the preposition “for” + noun or pronoun. The same as “ricordare”.

Comment: I disagree. "to wait" may be used intransitively (eg I'll wait here) or transitively (eg I am waiting for you). That also applies to "ricordarsi". Based on the very core definition of verb transitivity, there can be no  object associated with a verb when it is used intransitively.

Comment: A transitive verb is not followed by any preposition and needs the object (in Italian complemento oggetto). An intransitive verb is followed by a preposition + noun,  y another verb, or by nothing al all.

Comment: To be waiting for + sb is not a transitive form. It should be “to be waiting sb” which in eng is uncorrect.

Comment: CB18 and @AlanEvangelista, please, it's not too meaningful taking examples from English to talk about transitivity in Italian. They are different languages with different phenomenons (phrasal verbs, for instance, don't exist in Italian, in a first approximation).

Comment: @CB18 You are right, "to wait" is also used intransitively in "to wait for you", as English considers "for you" a prepositional complement. Sorry for my confusion. And indeed sometimes some grammar concepts are not defined identically in different languages. My point is that I thought that "di qualcosa" would be an indirect object in "ricordarsi di qualcosa" in Italian. However, based on your answer, I think now that it is, in fact, a prepositional complement?